# How can I customize the tab-to-space conversion factor in VS Code?

Tags: visual-studio-code

How do I customize the tab-to-space conversion factor when using Visual Studio Code?

For instance, right now in HTML it appears to produce two spaces per press of <kbd>TAB</kbd>, but in TypeScript it produces 4.

Answer (score 2061, accepted):

By default, Visual Studio Code will try to guess your indentation options depending on the file you open.

You can turn off indentation guessing via `"editor.detectIndentation": false`.

You can customize this easily via these three settings for **Windows** in menu *File* → *Preferences* → *Settings* or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>,</kbd> and for **Mac** in menu *Code* → *Preferences* → *Settings* or <kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>,</kbd>:

```js
// The number of spaces a tab is equal to. This setting is overridden
// based on the file contents when `editor.detectIndentation` is true.
"editor.tabSize": 4,

// Insert spaces when pressing Tab. This setting is overriden
// based on the file contents when `editor.detectIndentation` is true.
"editor.insertSpaces": true,

// When opening a file, `editor.tabSize` and `editor.insertSpaces`
// will be detected based on the file contents. Set to false to keep
// the values you've explicitly set, above.
"editor.detectIndentation": false
```

Comment: Hey Guss, would you be willing to point me to a file where the guessing is wrong? Also please share how you've configured these two settings (tabSize & insertSpaces) and what you would expect to get. Thanks! :)

Comment: I have configured both settings to "auto", and the behavior is not as I expect (though I wouldn't go as far as to call it "wrong"). I don't know what file should be changed to support my convention, but I opened a [uservoice ticket for that](http://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/293070-visual-studio-code/suggestions/7853865-allow-to-configure-the-auto-behavior-of-features), as suggested in the answer to [question #30057721](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30057721/)

Comment: Is there also an option to set the default for new, blank files? There's not much to guess in that scenario and I think VSCode will default to using spaces (which I don't prefer)...

Comment: Fwiw, there's also a [workplace settings](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/settings#_creating-user-and-workspace-settings) option so that you can set a different behavior by project that overrides user settings. 2¢

Comment: Thanks ruffin. Is there a way to change `tabSize` per language? e.g. when editing multiple files with different languages in the same Workspace (e.g. Ruby, JavaScript, CSS, etc.) - Ruby would be `2` spaces, but CSS would be `4`... usually.

Comment: So when I'm don't like soft tab length, I just convert to tabs and to spaces again.

Comment: If you have a `.editorconfig` file, it overrides all tab size. Make sure you have `indent_size = 4` in that file

Comment: (Deleted my previous comment.) It looks like this controls the indentation that will be used in a file in future, but what I actually want is to control the "width" with which existing tabs in a file are displayed. (E.g. if I open an ad-hoc tab-separated (TSV-like) file, I'd like to temporarily set the tab width to a large number like 50 so that the tab-separated "columns" in a file show up far apart. I'm able to do this in other editors…) Is this not configurable in VS Code?

Answer (score 1025):

I'm running version 1.21, but I think this may apply to other versions as well.

Take a look at the bottom right-hand side of the screen. You should see something that says `Spaces` or `Tab-Size`.

Mine shows spaces, →

[image]

1. Click on the *Spaces* (or *Tab-Size*)
2. Choose *Indent Using Spaces* or *Indent using Tabs*
3. Select the amount of spaces or tabs you like.

This only works per document, not project-wide. If you want to apply it project-wide, you need to also add `"editor.detectIndentation": false` to your user settings.

Comment: how is #3 done? After choosing #2, there doesn't appear to be a way to just "select the amount of spaces ... you like". Thanks.

Comment: Wow. All this time I was tricked by that weird drop-down-list-as-context-menu UI element, when I only needed one more click to get to the number I can change. Thank you. After doing step #2, a new weird drop-down-list-as-context-menu UI element appears, letting me select a number from a list.

Comment: @Chris22 It should appear in an input bar at the top of the screen

Comment: @Tricky ah, yes, i see it. thanks.  i'm not sure why i didn't see that before

Comment: If you have a `.editorconfig` file, it overrides all tab size. Make sure you have `indent_size = 4` in that file

Answer (score 285):

### **Note**

If you are talking about [**prettier**](https://prettier.io/) for `tabSize`, go to the Method 2 of this answer.

### **Method 1 (VS Code Way)**

Well, if you like the developer way, Visual Studio Code allows you to specify the different file types for the `tabSize`. Here is the example of my `settings.json` with default four spaces and JavaScript/JSON two spaces:

PS: Well, if you do not know how to open this file (specially in a new version of Visual Studio Code), you can:

1. Left-bottom gear →
2. Settings → top right *Open Settings*

[image]

```json
{
  // I want my default to be 4, but JavaScript/JSON to be 2
  "editor.tabSize": 4,
  "[javascript]": {
    "editor.tabSize": 2
  },
  "[json]": {
    "editor.tabSize": 2
  },

  // This one forces the tab to be **space**
  "editor.insertSpaces": true
}
```

---

### **Method 2 (If using prettier)**

If you are using prettier, things may be different again, prettier has 2 level of setting for this:

1. User level, which you can click the extension and click setting find the keyword `tabWidth`
2. Project level, which you can add/update from the root project level in file `.prettierrc`

Comment: Doesn't work here... Can't get to know why...

Comment: @bck are you using pretter? that case may be different, you might need to change extension setting or the project file `.prettierrc`.

Answer (score 127):

By default, Visual Studio Code auto-detects the indentation of the current open file. If you want to switch this feature off and make all indentation, for example, two spaces, you'd do the following in your `User Settings` or `Workspace` settings.

```json
{
   "editor.tabSize": 2,
   "editor.detectIndentation": false
}
```

Answer (score 88):

We can **control tab size by file type** with [EditorConfig](https://editorconfig.org/) and its [EditorConfig for VS Code](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=EditorConfig.EditorConfig) extension. We then can make <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>F</kbd> specific to each file type.

### Installation

Open the VS Code command palette with <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>P</kbd> and paste this:

```
ext install EditorConfig
```

### Example Configuration

#### .editorconfig

```
[*]
indent_style = space

[*.{js,ts,json}]
indent_size = 2

[*.java]
indent_size = 4

[*.go]
indent_style = tab
```

#### settings.json

EditorConfig overrides whatever settings.json configures for the editor. There is no need to change `editor.detectIndentation`.

Comment: What is this `ext` you speak of (please respond by editing your answer, not here in comments (as appropriate))? Some Node.js thingy? What platform?

Comment: @PeterMortensen You can do a `CTRL+P` and paste the `ext install EditorConfig` it's a shortcut installation command specific to Vscode.

Answer (score 25):

If you use the `prettier` extension in Visual Studio Code, try adding this to the `settings.json` file:

```json
"editor.insertSpaces": false,
"editor.tabSize": 4,
"editor.detectIndentation": false,

"prettier.tabWidth": 4,
"prettier.useTabs": true  // This made it finally work for me
```

Comment: why does prettier just use the editor.tabSize (

Comment: Thank you!! "prettier.tabWidth": 4,
"prettier.useTabs": true  did it for me - i lost like 2 hours on this :)

Answer (score 19):

In **Visual Studio Code** version 1.31.1 or later (I think): Like sed **Alex Dima**, you can customize this easily via these settings for

- Windows in menu *File* → *Preferences* → *User Settings* or use short keys <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>P</kbd>
- Mac in menu *Code* → *Preferences* → *Settings* or <kbd>⌘</kbd>,

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 15):

There are already lots of good answers provided by our beloved community members. I actually wanted to add the C# code `tabSize` and found this thread. There are many solutions I found and official [VS Code docs](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/settings#_language-specific-editor-settings) is awesome. I just want to share my C# setting:

```json
"[csharp]": {
    "editor.insertSpaces": true,
    "editor.tabSize": 4
},
```

Just copy and paste above code to your `settings.json` file and save. thanks

Comment: Yeah, this is the way to go if you want to set a different format for a specific language. I like using tabs with tabWidth=2, but autopep8 just hates that.

Answer (score 11):

1. CTRL + comma
2. Search for indent using tabs
3. Go and change Editor: **Tab Size**

[image]

That's aLL

Comment: That's patently **not** all. Need to also consider auto-detect and the current file settings.

Answer (score 9):

In your bottom-right corner, you have Spaces:
[Spaces: 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mPW7B.jpg)

There you can change the indentation according to your needs:
[Indentation Options](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nGcTj.jpg)

Comment: many answers above you telling me how I can turn off the manual detection for all files - but yours was the first I spotted that actually told me how to change how many spaces it was detecting :)  followed it up with "Format Document" - Shift-Alt-F to pretty print and adjust to the new Space-Tab-Indention depts

Answer (score 9):

Since 2023 there is a new setting **`editor.indentSize`** to set the indentation size separately from tab stop size.

This is particularly useful for editing legacy code which relies on 8-space tabs but uses fewer spaces for indentation.

Here's an example configuration for a **4**-space indentation, while aligning actual TABs on **8** spaces:

```
  "editor.insertSpaces": true,
  "editor.indentSize": 4,
  "editor.tabSize": 8,
```

[image: tabStopWidth]

Answer (score 8):

That is `lonefy.vscode-js-css-html-formatter` to blame. Disable it, and install `HookyQR.beautify`.

Now on save your tabs wouldn't be converted.

Answer (score 7):

You want to make sure your editorconfig is not conflicting with your user or workspace settings configuration, as I just had a bit of annoyance thinking the settings files settings were not being applied when it was my editor configuration undoing those changes.

Answer (score 7):

In Visual Studio Code version 1.14.1

- Select File > Preferences > Settings / press [Ctrl + ,]

[image: Go to settings]

- Select User > Commonly Used
- Set Tab Size to 4

[image: Change tab size]

Answer (score 6):

If the accepted answer on this post doesn't work, give this a try:

I had [EditorConfig for Visual Studio Code](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=EditorConfig.EditorConfig) installed in my editor, and it kept overriding my user settings which were set to indent files using spaces. Every time I switched between editor tabs, my file would automatically get indented with tabs even if I had converted indentation to spaces!!!

Right after I uninstalled this extension, indentation no longer changes between switching editor tabs, and I can work more comfortably rather than having to manually convert tabs to spaces every time I switch files - that is painful.

Comment: Oh my god.. I just struggled for some time trying to work out why my tabs would go back to using 4 spaces instead of 2. Once EditorConfig was uninstalled, it worked. Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

From [the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29972396/how-can-i-customize-the-tab-to-space-conversion-factor#comment106678399_29972553):

> Is there a way to change tabSize per language? e.g. when editing multiple files with different languages in the same Workspace (e.g. Ruby, JavaScript, CSS, etc.) - Ruby would be 2 spaces, but CSS would be 4... usually

That is why, with VSCode 1.63 (Nov. 2021), you have:

> ### [Multiple language specific editor settings](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-docs/blob/c659a03e5f7d538db15529c8337e4fa91b601bf7/release-notes/v1_63.md#multiple-language-specific-editor-settings)
>
> You can now configure language specific editor settings for multiple languages at once.
> Following example shows how you can customise settings for javascript and typescript languages together:
>
> ```
> "[javascript][typescript]": {
>   "editor.maxTokenizationLineLength": 2500
> }
> ```

In your case:

```json
"[ruby][html]": {
    "editor.insertSpaces": true,
    "editor.tabSize": 2
},
"[csharp][typescript]": {
    "editor.insertSpaces": true,
    "editor.tabSize": 4
},
```

---

You can also [change the tab size in terminals, with VSCode 1.75 (Jan. 2023)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75076189/6309).

Answer (score 5):

A much simpler approach is to use the in-built wildcard filter `@lang:` provided by Visual Studio Code.

### Steps

1. Click the settings icon (bottom left)
2. Select **Settings**
3. In the **Search Settings** input box type in `@lang:javascript tabsize`

This will filter all the settings and leave you with the options for javascript's `tabSize` only. Enter the tab factor you want and it will be applied to that language.

[image: Easy to follow steps]

> Please note
>
> - To have these settings applied to your user profile make sure the `User` tab is selected. If the `Workspace` tab is selected, **VSCode** will create a `.vscode` folder in your project folder with a `settings.json` file; this means whatever changes you will do only apply to the current workspace (project folder)
> - You can use this for any other language eg `@lang:php tabsize`

Answer (score 4):

@alex-dima's solution from 2015 will change tab sizes and spaces for all files and @Tricky's solution from 2016 appears to only change the settings for the current file.

As of 2017, I found another solution that works on a per-language basis. Visual Studio Code was not using the proper tab sizes or space settings for [Elixir](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elixir_(programming_language)), so I found that I could change the settings for all Elixir files.

I clicked on the language in the status bar ("Elixir" in my case), chose "Configure 'Elixir' language based settings...", and edited the Elixir-specific language settings. I just copied the "editor.tabSize" and "editor.insertSpaces" settings from the default settings on the left (I'm so glad those are shown) and then modified them on the right.

It worked great, and now all Elixir language files use the proper tab size and space settings.

Answer (score 4):

Menu *File* → *Preferences* → *Settings*

Add to user settings:

```
"editor.tabSize": 2,
"editor.detectIndentation": false
```

then right click your document if you have one opened already and click Format Document to have your existing document follow these new settings.

Answer (score 4):

When using TypeScript, the default tab width is always two regardless of what it says in the toolbar. You have to set "prettier.tabWidth" in your user settings to change it.

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>P</kbd>, *Type* → user settings, add:

```
"prettier.tabWidth": 4
```

Answer (score 2):

I had to do a lot of settings edits like the previous answers, so I don't know which made it work after a lot of modifications.

Nothing worked until I closed and openen my IDE, but the last three things I did was disable the `lonefy.vscode-js-css-html-formatter`,  `"html.format.enable": true,` and restart Visual Studio.

```
{
    "editor.suggestSelection": "first",
    "vsintellicode.modify.editor.suggestSelection": "automaticallyOverrodeDefaultValue",
    "workbench.colorTheme": "Default Light+",
    "[html]": {
        "editor.defaultFormatter": "vscode.html-language-features",
        "editor.tabSize": 2,
        "editor.detectIndentation": false,
        "editor.insertSpaces": true
    },
    "typescript.format.insertSpaceAfterOpeningAndBeforeClosingTemplateStringBraces": true,
    "editor.tabSize": 2,
    "typescript.format.insertSpaceAfterConstructor": true,
    "files.autoSave": "afterDelay",
    "html.format.indentHandlebars": true,
    "html.format.indentInnerHtml": true,
    "html.format.enable": true,
    "editor.detectIndentation": false,
    "editor.insertSpaces": true,
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I tried to change editor`.tabSize` to 4, but `.editorConfig` overrides whatever settings I had specified, so there is no need to change any configuration in user settings. You just need to edit .editorConfig file:

```
set indent_size = 4
```

Answer (score 0):

If this is for Angular 2, and the CLI is generating files which you would like differently formatted, you can edit these files to change what is generated:

```
npm_modules/@angular/cli/blueprints/component/files/__path__/*
```

Not massively recommended as an npm update will delete your work, but it has saved me a lot of time.

Answer (score -1):

User3550138 is correct. `lonefy.vscode-js-css-html-formatter` overrides all the settings mentioned in other answers. However, you don't have to disable or uninstall it as it can be configured.

Full instructions can be found by opening the extensions sidebar and clicking on this extension and it will display configuration instructions in the editor workspace. At least it does for me in Visual Studio Code version 1.14.1.