# How to change the per-language configuration of setting "editor.insertSpaces" to "auto"

Tags: visual-studio-code, polyglot

I'm using VS Code to edit projects in multiple languages (mostly Ruby, PHP and Javascript) and for each language we have different indentation models (spaces/tabs and width). Looks like VS Code supports this as it allows both `editor.insertSpaces` and `editor.tabSize` to be set to `"auto"` which is a per-language definition.

But while `editor.tabSize` looks to do about what I want, `editor.insertSpaces` always insert spaces when in `"auto"` mode.

I've tried to find where one can edit the per-language configuration but have found no such setting. I've also looked in the language directories under `resources/app/client/vs/languages` but have failed to find something that specifies these features.

Any idea how to customize the per-language settings?

Comment: I wish `vscode` start supporting plugins and specially `editorconfig` for this use case.

Comment: Please suggest this as a feature on our User Voice page: http://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/293070-visual-studio-code

Comment: i've opened [uservoice ticket #7853865](http://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/293070-visual-studio-code/suggestions/7853865-allow-to-configure-the-auto-behavior-of-features)

Answer (score 23, accepted):

To use perlanguage settings, you use the `[language_id]` in square brackets:

example:

```
{
  "[typescript]": {
    "editor.formatOnSave": true,
    "editor.formatOnPaste": true
  },
  "[markdown]": {
    "editor.formatOnSave": true,
    "editor.wrappingColumn": 0,
    "editor.renderWhitespace": "all",
    "editor.acceptSuggestionOnEnter": false
  }
}
```

**Update:** `editor.tabSize` and `editor.insertSpaces` are now supported in version [1.10](https://code.visualstudio.com/updates/v1_10#_language-specific-editor-settings)

Comment: Thank you for the note on future support. That is what I came here for .

Comment: @Strake it's supported now!!

Comment: How do I do multiple languages ?

Comment: Fwiw, [to see a list of languages supported](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/settings#_language-specific-editor-settings)... "*To customize your editor by language, run the global command Preferences: Configure Language Specific Settings (command id: `workbench.action.configureLanguageBasedSettings`) from the Command Palette (⇧⌘P) which opens the language picker. Selecting the language you want, opens the Settings editor with the language entry where you can add applicable settings.*" Also had to restart VS Code, not just reopen window, for it to "take" when I did it initially.