# How to set per-filetype tab size in VS Code?

Tags: visual-studio-code

How to set tab size is already answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29972396/how-to-set-tab-space-style).

But how to have different settings for different file types?
E.g. I want the tab size for HTMLs to be 2, but for other files to be 4.

Answer (score 414, accepted):

VS Code configures [language specific settings](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/settings#_language-specific-editor-settings) in `settings.json`

- Shortcut is: Command Palette (⇧⌘P) then: Preferences: Configure Language Specific Settings

Example of setting.json changing tabsize

```json
{
    // this is the default for all languages, unless otherwise specified.
    "editor.tabSize": 4,
    "[sass]": {
        "editor.tabSize": 2
    },
    "[html]": {
        "editor.tabSize": 4
    },
    "[javascript]": {
        "editor.tabSize": 2
    }
}
```

These are not nested inside any other object, they are defined at the root.

Comment: You probably need to add
"editor.detectIndentation": false

Comment: using this system, it seems impossible to set a tabSize for `.travis.yml`

Comment: @ChaseMoskal It is possible to set per language, and in your case Yaml files. FYI... .yml = yaml
https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/settings#_language-specific-editor-settings
    "[yaml]": {
        "editor.tabSize": 2
    },

Comment: Beware that [EditorConfig](https://editorconfig.org/) will override any VS Code setting you may have related to file formatting.

Comment: `Ctrl + Shift + P` for Windows users when opening Command Palette

Comment: I'm unable to set the `tabSize` for JSON files with `"[json]": { "editor.tabSize": 2 }`

Comment: If people are using the EditorConfig extension, also note that child directories can override the root file's settings. And if the child directory has `root = true`, the extension will not go to parent directories to look for overrides. This happened to me when I used the Angular CLI to generate a new app in a sub directory of a mono repo. Angular expects their `.editorconfig` file to be the root, and it uses 2 spaces for tabs.

Answer (score 22):

With vscode v1.63 you will be able to "group" languages in language-specific settings like this:

```
"[sass][javascript]": {
    "editor.tabSize": 2
},
"[html]": {
    "editor.tabSize": 4
}
```

This already can be done in the `colorCustomizations` setting like:

```
"workbench.colorCustomizations": {
    "[GitHub Sharp][GitHub Sharp Dark]": {
       "editorPane.background": "#d6d0d01a",
       "sideBarSectionHeader.border": "#D3D3D3",
    }
}
```

See [Multiple languages specific editor settings](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/51935)

Answer (score 7):

In addition to the other answers, you can set a default, and then set file-specific sizes.

```
  "editor.tabSize": 2,     // default
  "[elm]": {               // specific only to .elm files
      "editor.tabSize": 4
  },
```