# Managing Indentation Settings in VS Code

Tags: visual-studio-code, settings

I'm really liking VS Code, but I've looked everywhere and I can't seem to change one very annoying feature: pressing return on an empty indented line carries over the current indentation, but removes all indentation on the original line. It seems impossible to have two consecutive tab-indented lines in the editor.

Is there a setting I'm missing or some other way to preserve the tab-indentation across lines? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

We can setup user settings for this, 
Go to File > Preferences > User Settings:

You can customize this easily via these 3 settings in 
/ The number of spaces a tab is equal to. This setting is overriden
// based on the file contents when `editor.detectIndentation` is true.
"editor.tabSize": 4,

// Insert spaces when pressing Tab. This setting is overriden
// based on the file contents when `editor.detectIndentation` is true.
"editor.insertSpaces": true,

// When opening a file, `editor.tabSize` and `editor.insertSpaces`
// will be detected based on the file contents.
"editor.detectIndentation": true

For more information - 
We can setup user settings for this, 
Go to File > Preferences > User Settings:

You can customize this easily via these 3 settings in 
/ The number of spaces a tab is equal to. This setting is overriden
// based on the file contents when `editor.detectIndentation` is true.
"editor.tabSize": 4,

// Insert spaces when pressing Tab. This setting is overriden
// based on the file contents when `editor.detectIndentation` is true.
"editor.insertSpaces": true,

// When opening a file, `editor.tabSize` and `editor.insertSpaces`
// will be detected based on the file contents.
"editor.detectIndentation": true

For more info you can check here - [How to set tab-space style?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29972396/how-to-set-tab-space-style)

Answer (score 0):

I have figured out my problem:

In Settings, "editor.trimAutoWhitespace" is true by default, meaning any trailing tabs left on a line are automatically deleted, even if they are just holding the regular indentation level. I have fixed my problem by setting this option to false in my User Settings (File / Preferences / Settings).

I am surprised that I can't find any record of anyone else having found this behavior unusual.