# How can I configure wrapping indent size in VS Code?

Tags: visual-studio-code

In my case, the default 'wrapping indentation' size is always 4 spaces.

I want to change this size. How can I configure this?

Comment: This looks like a duplicate of a solved question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29972396/how-to-set-tab-space-style

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Click the gear on left bottom, then choose `Settings` and search `wrappingIndent` in settings, you can config it.
[image]

Comment: I want to change wrapping indent size with actual values, like 1 or 2 bytes. Is it impossible?

Comment: Checking the source code: https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/blob/1ba11c0ef4902d29787b39110444b177ad4adafd/src/vs/editor/common/viewModel/characterHardWrappingLineMapper.ts

Comment: they somehow changed it. It cannot be found anymore.. :/

Comment: Ah found it. Will create a new answer

Answer (score 2):

Click the gear on left bottom, then choose Settings and search "wrapping indent" in settings. Here you can set it to "indent".

[image]

Comment: not good enough. the wrap depth needs to have a different space width than the indent width i.e: + 0.5, otherwise it is confusing.

Comment: @Hogdotmac There are several options in the drop down menu. Selecting "deepindent" gives the wrapped line +2 indentation. Your overall tab settings (ex: 2 space tabs versus 4 space tabs) will affect the perceived amount of indentation.