# Change the default tab size in VS Code for Flutter projects

Tags: flutter, visual-studio-code

When I create a new flutter project using flutter create and open the project in VSCode it always says the configured tab size is 2 when my user settings say it should be 4 and I can't find anywhere that says that tab size is configured to be 2.

Does anyone have any idea where it is configured this way?

Edit: The question: [How can I customize the tab-to-space conversion factor?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29972396/how-can-i-customize-the-tab-to-space-conversion-factor) does not help to answer my question as I've already tried those steps. The issue here is something is overriding the settings in VSCode for the flutter project and I can't seem to figure out what it is.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I customize the tab-to-space conversion factor?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29972396/how-can-i-customize-the-tab-to-space-conversion-factor)

Comment: No unfortunately it doesn't. I've done all of that already.

Comment: Please [edit] to show/describe things you already tried so that people will not suggest duplicates that could get your question closed. As indicated in [ask]: "*including links to related questions that haven't helped can help others in understanding how your question is different from the rest*".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As an update to this. I was digging around in the dart/flutter documentation and I found out that the formatter for dart code was deliberately made so that it wasn't configurable so there is nothing I can do here.