# How to achieve "neat" line breaking for several arguments in Python + VSCode?

Tags: python, code-organization

I am new to Python and I couldn't find the answer for this precise question elsewhere. Let's say one is using a Python function with several inputs. Ideally, for readability, I would like to write code as

```
my_variable = my_function (arg1 = bla_bla_bla_1,
                           arg2 = bla_bla_bla_2,
                           arg3 = bla_bla_bla_3)
```

This is very easy on RStudio with, for example, just using <kbd>Enter</kbd>. I am using Python on Visual Studio Code but I can't find a way to do it. Ideally, it would look like this:

[image]

But of course such code won't run since <kbd>Enter</kbd> and <kbd>Tab</kbd> or <kbd>Space</kbd> will break it. Is there anyway to achieve this? I see that this is different than, let's say, code wrapping. But I don't know the name of this property/way of writing code. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Using `\` should do the trick like so:

```
a = [5,4,6,\
     4,5,6]
```

Comment: Beat it to me, thats exactly the way to do it

Comment: @SebastianCristiCastillo If you use `()` or `[]` you don't need the `\` character

Comment: @rioV8 and why you tag me to say it...?

Answer (score 0):

Python is quite prescriptive about style. The spec is known as PEP-8 https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/

You can install a “linter” in VSCode which will alert you to general style breaches. See https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/linting

For your specific question, I think this is the prescribed way.

```
variable = my_function(
    arg1 = bla_bla_bla_1,
    arg2 = bla_bla_bla_2,
    arg3 = bla_bla_bla_3,
)
```

You might disagree, but python doesn’t leave much room for your opinion on this . This can be frustrating at first, but when embraced allows you to focus on coding instead of style; and, crucially, a standard style ensures readability when code is shared by multiple python developers.

Comment: I am fine with conventions and I agree this is helpful! How do you actually get what you wrote? You press enter and adjusts with spaces? Thanks!

Comment: Enter for a new line and tab to ident. You should be able to set VSCode such that when pressing tab it inserts 4 spaces instead of a tab character

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29972396/how-can-i-customize-the-tab-to-space-conversion-factor#29972553 Will answer how to setup your indentation