# Do Visual studio code and Atom replace Tabs with space?

Tags: visual-studio-code, atom-editor, text-editor, code-editor

Stupid question but...here we go

I recently switch from Atom to Vscode, in Atom I always have used tabs(4)( mixed with spaces of course), I notice that vscode use 2 tabs by default; nothing important. But I decide to see how the files I've wrote with Atom looks like in vscode because I read that tabs looks quite different in others environments, but that wasn't the case, its looks exactly as on atom, I tried opening files written on Vscode  in  atom and vice versa , as well in notepad, even in WordPad and it's still looked find... I think it's because they use space when you press tab, but searching in the internet seems that isn't the case; tabs are tabs in atom, or in any other code editor/ide. Is this true?

Notice:(I don't know how to use "in" and "on" correctly yet).

Comment: vscode uses the user preferences, you can set it to explicitly use spaces always, tab always, or based on the file. See here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29972396/how-can-i-customize-the-tab-to-space-conversion-factor

Comment: Thank you so much :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

open any file and look for the right down corner of the vscode. There you will see which character vscode is using for `tab`

[image: tab or spaces]

In this picture, the file is python, configured to use **4 spaces** as tabs.