# Rearrange/Remove spaces from multiple lines in VSCODE

Tags: visual-studio-code

Is there a way where i can rearrange/ reorder multiple lines in VSCODE

For eg; I have something like this, (many lines). Not necessarly at the start of the line.

```py
    =
  = 
= 
   =
     =
```

and i would like it be rearranged as,

```py
=
=
=
=
```

I know some tricks, select multiple lines with `ctrl + alt + up/down` key and then move or indent using `ctrl + ]` but it is not efficient. Tab + space customisation is explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29972396/how-can-i-customize-the-tab-to-space-conversion-factor/29972553)

Is there a specific key to do this in one go? Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2):

For this case, I believe selecting all the content you wish to rearrange and holding the <kbd>shift</kbd> key while pressing the <kbd>tab</kbd> key will move everything back. Continue pressing the <kbd>tab</kbd> key until you are satisfied with the result.