# Eslint thinks a tab is 4 spaces

Tags: javascript, node.js, eslint, visual-studio-code

When using ESLint in Microsoft Visual Studio Code, ESLint is deciding that my tab is four spaces. When I click 'quick fix' and 'fix this indent problem' it fixes it fine, but why is my tab key not inserting a tab ESLint recognizes? I have read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29972396/how-can-i-customize-the-tab-to-space-conversion-factor) and turned off `editor.insertSpaces` but that does not seem to have fixed it. Any idea how to get ESLint to register my tabs? I would prefer not to disable the rule entirely, but I will if I have to.

Edit: it would seem that this problem only occurs in my index.js file.

Comment: Does this help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29972396/how-can-i-customize-the-tab-to-space-conversion-factor

Comment: Unfortunately that is the one I read prior, and changing the insertSpaces rule did not work, ill try the others though.

Comment: I think `"editor.tabSize": 2,` might be what you're looking for. There's also the option of manually copy/pasting a tab character that the linter expects

Comment: That did work, however now my tabs are skinny, can I do it somehow keeping the other tab size?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I customize the tab-to-space conversion factor?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29972396/how-can-i-customize-the-tab-to-space-conversion-factor)

Comment: Yes it did, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `settings.json` file, you should add this line:

```json
"editor.tabSize": 2
```

Comment: That did work, however now my tabs are skinny, can I do it somehow keeping the other tab size?

Comment: What do you mean by that? Can you eleborate?

Comment: Ah never mind, it seems to have fixed itself, I just meant the tab sizes shrank.