# How could I adjust the height of each azure service in Visual Studio Code?

Tags: azure, visual-studio-code

[VS code capture image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FoGtL.png)

As shown in the capture image(with red arrow in the image), I want to adjust the height of each Azure service.
Please let me know how to do this. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I want to adjust the height of each Azure service. Please let me know
> how to do this

There is such  limitation in VS CODE to minimize and maximize up to certain level the Side bar Azure services ,

To  do that you can do the below steps:

- Hide  your azure service below which you want to adjust  as shown

[image]

- Drag down the line which is up in the LOGIC APPS (STANDARD) as shown :
  [image]

Drag down according to your requirement
[image]

To know more about configuration in VS CODE please refer the below links :

. SO THREAD - # [How can I customize the tab-to-space conversion factor?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29972396/how-can-i-customize-the-tab-to-space-conversion-factor)

VS CODE Blog : [User and Workspace Settings](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/settings)

**UPDATE:**

Please make sure that you have **update** your VS Code version to `1.62.3` and then try. also check my `settings.json` file .
Go to settings if you haven't update you will get an option called **restart to update** instead of Check for update .
[image]
[image]

Comment: [AjayKumarGhose-MT]It does NOT work for me. For me, up-down arrow as shown in your second & third captured image does NOT appear. I think there would be some settings for activating(or enabling) the up/down arrow. Could you upload your settings.json file? Thanks.

Comment: Thanks @SiG Kim I have updated the answer, If its helpful could you please mark it as an answer so that it will beneficial to other community members for similar issue .Thanks:)

Comment: It is very weird. I just copied your json file. But it didn't work. After "check for updates", "There are currently no updates available" messages appeared. But like charming, it WORKED!! Thanks @AjayKumarGhose-MT.

Comment: Thanks @SiG Kim Glad to be of help :) .