# The tab key does not work in Visual Studio code

Tags: visual-studio-code, tabs

I downloaded vs code (on MacOS) and in any files in any programming languages ​​by pressing the tab key for me I doesn’t put 4 spaces like it was before. I don’t know what’s wrong.

I tried to find it in the vs code settings but I couldn’t find anything. I would be very grateful if someone tells me how to fix this.

Comment: Does the tab key work in notepad?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/29972553/9107694 Does this help?

Comment: I suspect the `editor.insertSpaces` setting. check to see if that setting is changed at any scope (user, profile, multi-root workspace, workspace, language mode)

Comment: Everything works in notepad.

Comment: I tried the link you sent, but it still didn’t help.

Comment: I also tried changing the parameter: editor.insertSpaces but that didn't help either

Comment: I also want to add that the keyboard shortcuts cmd+shift+m ​​did not give any result