# How to make Prettier do 4-space indent in place of 2?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions, prettier

I use Google formatting style. I also use

```
{
   "editor.TabWidth": 4
}
```

but it still uses 2 spaces

Code:

```
int main() {
  std::cout << "Hello, World!\n";
  return 0;
}
```

(As you see, there only 2 space in place of tab)

Settings:

```
    "[cpp]": {
    "editor.tabSize": 4,
    "editor.defaultFormatter": "ms-vscode.cpptools"
},
"cmake.configureOnOpen": true,
"prettier.tabWidth": 4,
"prettier.useTabs": true,
"python.formatting.provider": "none",
"editor.detectIndentation": false,
"editor.insertSpaces": true
```

If I set Visual Studio formatting style, it will use tab. If there is a way to disable moving the curly brace after the method, I will use it
Actually, indents works well for python and java. Problem appears only with c++

I've already tried to use

```
editor.TabWidth
```

It didn't help me too:
[How can I customize the tab-to-space conversion factor?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29972396/how-can-i-customize-the-tab-to-space-conversion-factor)

Comment: in what file are you putting your `editor."TabWidth" = 4`? And why are the quotes in a weird place?

Comment: @starball this is settings.json And I do not understand what you men about quotes... This was done automatically by VSCode

Comment: what is the `editor.TabWidth` setting? you say you put it in settings.json. I have no such setting in my VS Code. Is it coming from an extension?

Comment: @starball as far as I know it is a native VS Code setting. I found it in tutorial that had to help me, but... They didn't